# Java 2D Lighting Effect

Tags: java, graphics, 2d

I'm trying to replicate the lighting effect shown on each of the bars in the image below in Java 2D. I really don't even know where to start as I have no Java 2D experience.

Can anyone offer me some pointers?

[image]

Comment: +1 for being relatively clear compared to other questions on this site. Maybe a little more clarificaton would be nice. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are basic gradients applied to rectangles and other polygons.

You can use [`GradientPaint`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GradientPaint.html) to create a gradient effect.

```
g.setPaint(yourGradientPaint);
g.draw(yourShape);
```